# C sockets, Incomplete file transfer

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, blocking

I'm writing a **C** program to **transfer a file of fixed size**, a little over 2Mb, from a server to a client. I'm using **TCP sockets** on **Linux** and the code I wrote is the following:

**Server (sender)**

```
while (1) {
    int nread = read(file, buffer, bufsize);
    if (nread == 0) // EOF 
        break;

    if (nread < 0) {
        // handle errors
    }

    char* partial = buffer;
    while (nread > 0) {
        int nwrite = write(socket, partial, nread);
        if (nwrite <= 0) {
            // handle errors
        }
        nread   -= nwrite;
        partial += nwrite;
    }
}

// file sent
shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR);
```

**Client (receiver)**

```
while (filesize > 0) {
    nread = read(socket, buffer, bufsize);
    if (nread == 0) {
        // EOF - if we reach this point filesize is still > 0
        // so the transfer was incomplete
        break;
    }

    if (nread < 0) {
        // handle errors
    }

    char* partial = buffer;
    while (nread > 0) {
        nwrite = write(file, partial, nread);
        if (nwrite <= 0) {
            // handle errors
        }
        nread    -= nwrite;
        partial  += nwrite;
        filesize -= nwrite;
    }
}

if (filesize > 0) {
    // incomplete transfer
    // handle error
}

close(socket);
```

When testing the code on my laptop (both client and server "are" on localhost and the communication happen on the loopback interface), sometimes the client exits because `read` received an **EOF**, and not because it received all `filesize` bytes. Since i use a `shutdown` on the server, this should mean that there is no other data to read.
(Note that the server sent all the bytes and executed the `shutdown` correctly)

Can you explain me why this is happening?

Where are the missing bytes gone?

**-----**

**EDIT 1 - Clarifications**

Some users asked a couple of clarifications so i am posting the answers here:

- The program is using **TCP blocking** sockets
- The `filesize` is a fixed value and is hardcoded in both client and server.
- **No** special socket options as, for example, **SO_LINGER** are enabled/used.
- When the error occur, the server (sender) has already sent all the data and executed the   `shutdown` correctly.
- The error, as of today, never happened when testing the application with the client and the server on different machines (transfer over a real network interface and not a loopback interface)

**EDIT 2**

User **Cornstalks** [pointed me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476348/c-sockets-incomplete-file-transfer#comment39760010_25476348) to a really interesting [article](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable) about the, non always reliable, behaviours of TCP.

The article, which is well worth a read, describe a few tricks useful when sending an unknown amount of data between TCP sockets. The tricks described are the followings:

1. Take advantage of the SO_LINGER option on the sender. This will help to keep the socket open, upon a call to `close(2)` or `shutdown(2)`, until all the data has successfully been sent.
2. On the receiver, beware of pending readable data before the actual receiving loop. It could lead to an immediate reset being sent.
3. Take advantage of `shutdown(2)` to signal the receiver the the sender has done sending data.
4. Let the receiver know the size of the file that will be sent before actually sending the file.
5. Let the receiver acknowledge the sender that the receiving loop is over. This will help to prevent the sender from closing the socket too soon.

After reading the article, i upgraded my code to implement the tricks number 1 and 5.

This is how i implemented trick number 5:

**Server (sender)**

```
// sending loop ...

// file sent
shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR);

// wait acknowledgement from the client
ack = read(socket, buffer, bufsize);
if (ack < 0) {
    // handle errors
}
```

**Client (receiver)**

```
// receiving loop..

if (filesize > 0) {
    // incomplete transfer
    // handle error
}

// send acknowledgement to the server
// this will send a FIN and trigger a read = 0 on the server
shutdown(socket, SHUT_WR);

close(socket);
```

**What about tricks number 2, 3 and 4?**

**Trick number 2** is not needed because as soon as the server accepts the connection the application proceed to the file transfer. NO extra messages are exchanged.

**Trick number 3** is already implemented

**Trick number 4** is also already implemented. As mentioned earlier the file size is hardcoded, so there is no need to exchange it.

**Did this solve my original problem?**

**NO** my problem was not solved. The error is still happening, and as of today, it only happened when testing the application with both client and server on localhost.

What do you think?

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you setting any special options or modes on the socket us as SO_LINGER or non-blocking options?

Comment: How does the client know the value of `filesize` before the transfer begins?

Comment: yes, TCP Blocking sockets and no, NO special options as SO_LINGER. The only socket option i used is SO_REUSEADDR on the server, but it shouldn't be the cause of this. The filesize if fixed, is always the same and is a little over 2 Mb

Comment: You might be interested in [why is my tcp not reliable](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable).

Comment: these details seem to be ignored in your code: The maximum send buffer size is 1 048 576 bytes. The default value of the SO_SNDBUF option is 32 767. For a TCP socket, the maximum length that you can specify is 1 GB.  Since you state that you did not setup the socket options, your trying to write 2m bytes into a 32k buffer.

Comment: You might want to use epollout to assure all the data is actually sent before closing the socket.

Comment: @Cornstalks that was an interesting read! Please take a look at "EDIT 2" on my question..

Comment: @user3629249 sorry but i don't quite understand what you are saying. are you implying that i should set a SO_SNDBUF as big as the file i have to send?

Comment: Perhaps you got a partial write as a consequence of write(2)  For a connection it is not warranted that you'll get all the bytes written in one chunck.  You have to loop until all of them have been written or refill the buffer each time.

Comment: Sorry, why do you consider write(2) result == 0 to be an error?  That's a condition you are not going to have, but write(2) system call doesn't return 0 as an error result.  Have you checked you are not receiving 0 as a write result?

Comment: @LuisColorado I count `write == 0` as an error because, from my understanding of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), (i'm quoting) _if the O_NONBLOCK flag is clear, write() shall block the calling thread until the data can be accepted_, implies that in case of success, something > 0 is returned. While testing this particular bug of mine a `write == 0` never happened, in fact, to be precise, a `write != nread` never happend.

Answer (score 0):

You're:

1. assuming that `read` fills the buffer, even though
2. you're defending magnificently against `write()` not writing the entire buffer.

You need to do (1), and you don't need to do (2) because you're in blocking mode and POSIX assures that `write()` doesn't return until all the data is written.

A simple version of both loops:

```
while ((nread = read(inFD, buffer, 0, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    write(outFD, buffer, 0, nread);
}
if (nread == -1)
    ; // error
```

A more correct version would check the result of `write()` for errors of course.

Comment: In your code, why read and write have 4 parameters instead of 3? Typo?

Comment: @EJP - how does this fix anything?  In the OP's code example he seems to be using the return value from read (`nread`) as the number of bytes to use in his write loops. His code doesn't appear to be assuming read returns a full buffer.

Comment: @selbie this doesn't fix my problem, i think @EJP only wanted to point out that my checks for partial `write` are not needed since i'm using a blocking socket.

Comment: I am not sure if _POSIX assures that write() doesn't return until all the data is written_ is accurate. See [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html): _If a write() requests that more bytes be written than there is room for, only as many bytes as there is room for shall be written... If write() is interrupted by a signal after it successfully writes some data, it shall return the number of bytes written._

Comment: I think there was a long debate on a older question about whether or not write/send on a blocking socket will ever return indicating only partial number of bytes sent. IIRC, save for errors, no one has ever seen `send` do this on a blocking socket. But no one is convinced that it's guaranteed.   `read` and `recv` definitely return partial data all the time.

Comment: write blocks until everything is written only for files, not for sockets.  You can get a partial write(2) from a socket on a slow start condition or on network congestion.  What's warranted is that you'll write at least one byte, but not more.